# Is the average Shannon's entropy of two groups of variables the mean of their two respective entropy values?

Tags: entropy

I have two groups of variables that respectively have Shannon's entropy of value X and Y.
Does it make sense to consider the average entropy of those two groups to be the mean between X and Y?

Comment: How is the "the average entropy of two groups" defined? It appears that this is a notion you came up with and you have essentially defined as you describe. It's up to you to decide whether this "definition" makes sense or not, depending on the problem you are dealing with